# Unnamed image in Avalon LayoutAnchorable title

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, avalondock

I am new to Avalon Dock. I created a LayoutAnchorable in LayoutAnchorablePane, but found there is an unnamed imaged created next to title textblock. It is not visible and focusable, but could be found in Accessibility Insights.

I am guessing it is converted from IconSource of LayoutAnchorable. However, when I changed the IconSource, the image didn't change.

Could someone tell me how to remove or hide this image from UI Automation Tree please? Or at least how to set a border for it (Currently Accessibility Insights keeps saying the image should not have null BoundingRectangle property)?

UI Automation Tree:
[UI Automation Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVwI6.png)

```
How found:  Selected from tree...
Name:   ""
ControlType:    UIA_ImageControlTypeId (0xC356)
LocalizedControlType:   "image"
IsEnabled:  true
IsOffscreen:    false
IsKeyboardFocusable:    false
HasKeyboardFocus:   false
AcceleratorKey: ""
AccessKey:  ""
ProcessId:  17588
RuntimeId:  [7.44B4.1486734]
AutomationId:   "icon"
FrameworkId:    "WPF"
ClassName:  "Image"
IsControlElement:   true
IsContentElement:   true
```

Related Code:

```
<adl:LayoutAnchorablePane DockHeight="300" DockWidth="500">
                        <adl:LayoutAnchorable Title="Experiments" ContentId="ExperimentsPane" AutoHideHeight="300" AutoHideWidth="1000" FloatingHeight="300" FloatingWidth="1000"  Closing="Closing">
                            <acPanes:Experiments x:Name="_ctlExperimentsPane" />
                        </adl:LayoutAnchorable>
</adl:LayoutAnchorablePane
```

```
<ad:DockingManager.AnchorableTitleTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{DynamicResource DefaultTextColor}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ad:DockingManager.AnchorableTitleTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind to show some screenshot picture of your anchorable header for better understanding?
I copy your code and it works just fine on my side.

Other than that, maybe you can try to remove most of your data binding. Start from **hardcoding** the header's title and content, then add the databinding one by one (start to monitoring all the changes when you add the databinding one by one). I think the issue comes from your databinding.

Comment: Thank for helping, Joshua! Finally I used an image source as Icon and succeeded. I don't know why it didn't work before.